# Rails 3: validate presence of at least one has many through association item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, associations, has-many-through

I have two models: `Project` and `ProjectDiscipline`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_disciplinizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :project_disciplines, through: :project_disciplinizations
  attr_accessible :project_discipline_ids
  attr_accessible :project_disciplines_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_disciplines, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
end

class ProjectDiscipline < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :project_disciplinizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :project_disciplinizations
end

class ProjectDisciplinization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_discipline_id, :project_id
  belongs_to :project_discipline
  belongs_to :project
end
```

On the new/edit `Project` form, I have a list of disciplines and a check box for each one of them so users can pick disciplines:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Check disciplines that apply</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:project_discipline_ids, ProjectDiscipline.order('name'), :id, :name, {}, {:class => 'checkbox'}) {|input| input.label(:class => 'checkbox') { input.check_box + input.text }} %>
    <p class="help-block">You must choose at least one discipline.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a validation to require that at least one discipline is checked. I've tried but I haven't figured out yet. How can I add this validation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Side note before the answer, based on the structure of your models I would use has_and_belongs_to_many instead of using this explicit linking model since it appears the linking model doesn't add anything of value.

Either way though, the answer is the same, which is to use a custom validation. Depending on whether you go with things the way they are or simplify to a has_and_belongs_to many you'll want to validate slightly differently.

```
validate :has_project_disciplines

def has_project_disciplines
  errors.add(:base, 'must add at least one discipline') if self.project_disciplinizations.blank?
end
```

or with has_and_belongs_to_many

```
validate :has_project_disciplines

def has_project_disciplines
  errors.add(:base, 'must add at least one discipline') if self.project_disciplines.blank?
end
```

Comment: Can you review my answer?

Comment: If you latter destroy the discipline, it could happen that a project has no disciplines anymore and thus is in an invalid state.

Comment: `.empty?` would be more appropriate here, blank queries returns the record from the DB, empty does `SELECT  1 AS one FROM `project_disciplines `  WHERE AND `project_disciplines `.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1`, which is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 16):

I prefer simpler approach:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :disciplines, presence: true
end
```

This code do absolutely the same as code by John Naegle or Alex Peachey, because of `validates_presence_of` exploit `blank?` method too.

Comment: Yes, but dependent on how your form is set up, there probably isn't a very good place to report an error, which will be attached to the :disciplines association (that doesn't exist).  The other approaches add the error to :base, which is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own validator

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :at_least_one_discipline

  private
  def at_least_one_discipline
    # Check that at least one exists after items have been de-selected
    unless disciplines.detect {|d| !d.marked_for_destruction? }
      errors.add(:disciplines, "must have at least one discipline")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you review my answer?