# Trouble with validation check for has_many :through association; how to create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Rails newbie here. I am having trouble with ensuring the presence of at least one "has_many :through" relationship in my users model.

I have:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :company_users

  #validates :company_users, presence: true
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :company_users   
end

class CompanyUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I got the commented `validates` line from the excellent answers at:

- [Validate that an object has one or more associated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535012/validate-that-an-object-has-one-or-more-associated-objects)
- [Rails 3: validate presence of at least one has many through association item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813084/rails-3-validate-presence-of-at-least-one-has-many-through-association-item)

However when I implement this line, then doing the following in rails console:

```
c = Company.create
c.users.create!(email: "test@example.com")
```

gives

```
`raise_validation_error': Validation failed: Company users can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

From my newbie perspective, it seems like the HMT entry isn't created until after the user is created, which creates a validation error preventing the user in the first place! It's probably a very simple error, but how do I get the above behaviour to work with that validation in place?

I have tried setting inverse_of in a couple place, without any success.

And before it's mentioned, I'm purposefully using HMT instead of HABTM because I have additional attributes on the company_users model that will be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to change the validation to

```
validates :companies, presence: true
```

and then create the user with

```
User.create(companies: [Company.create])
```

---

Edit:

Adding `inverse_of` to the CompanyUser model should also work. The validation would be left as `validate :company_users, presence: true`:

```
class CompanyUser
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :company_users
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Comment: This seems like it's not idiomatically correct and a bit of an awkward way of creating users? In any case, I don't understand how User.create(companies: [Company.create]) works. When I try calling ```User.create(email: "test@example.com", companies: c)``` as in the example above I get an ```method_missing': undefined method `each' for #<Company id: 5, ... ```

The standard workflow will be adding a user to one existing company when the user is created; and then adding the user to other companies later.

Comment: @NickGobin It should also be possible to add inverse_of to the CompanyUser model (answer edited). `User.create(email: 'test@example.com', companies: [c])` seems to have a clear intention to me i.e. it's creating a user who belongs to the given companies. An array needs to be passed in since a user can belong to many companies.

Comment: Yes! Adding inverse_of did it! I had actually tried that earlier without success, but this time I restarted the rails server in between. Not 100% sure if that was the only thing I did different to make it work this time, but it is definitely working now.
I need to read more on inverse_of, as it still confuses me a bit.
In any case, thank you!!